Is the torus as a bundle over the circle a vector bundle?
I was looking for an example of a smooth fiber bundle over a manifold that is not a vector bundle.
My idea was that $S^1 \times S^1 \overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} S^1$ has $S^1$ as Fibre, which doesn't have a vector space structure, through the fact that $\pi^{-1}(e^{it})$ gives you an entire circle and  $\pi^{-1}(U)$ with $U:= \{e^{i(t+ \varphi)} : \ t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \} \subset S^1$ gives you a tube.
On the other Hand, being a 2-manifold, the tangent on the tube has this $\sim \mathbb{R}^2$ vector space structure which could perhaps allow the torus to be a vector bundle over the circle.
However, I believe this cannot be the case because this vector space structure cannot be extended to the entire tube, due to the gluing.
Is this correct?
P.S. This argument would also imply that a cyclinder, seen as a bundle over a line $ \mathbb{R} \times S^1\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{R}$ isn't a vector bundle as well. (Which is perhaps the object I should have based my question on)

Briefly, "the torus is not (the total space of) a vector bundle over the circle," while the cylinder is the total space of a trivial real line bundle over the circle (but not over the line). <> "Is this correct?" is too coarse to answer as worded. ;)

Hint: Prove that the total space of a positive-dimensional vector bundle is never compact.
